# See the used amount of my free tier on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I run a small app in the AWS elastic beanstalk, and have the following problem: I *know* there is table somewhere, which shows you how much of your free tier you already used, but I'm just unable to find it for the sake of it. Maybe one could help.

The AWS space is truly confusing for a noob.

Comment: `free contingent` do you mean "free tier"?

Comment: @gusto2 yes, exactly

Comment: I'm not aware of any "table somewhere" that shows this exactly. Your best bet is to go into the billing dashboard and look at your current month's bill.

Comment: But there is, I'm absolutely sure as I've seen it a few times, but don't know where. And its not its own page, its rather a small table embedded on a site, showing you exact percentages of how much you already used of the free stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Tracking your free tier usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/tracking-free-tier-usage.html).

You can track your usage with the Top AWS Free Tier Services by Usage table on the dashboard of the [Billing and Cost Management console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home).

[image]